# Compare two CSV files and subtract a column of each if three things match

Tags: python, csv

I would like to write a python script that compares these two CSV files with Part numbers, and vendors in it. There is also a date in each file. What I'd like to have is a script that can compare rows and when they match subtract the date column. I have the script to get the difference in dates however I am not sure how to compare everything else within the CSV files.

Here Is a snippet of file 1:

```
Vendor ID,PO #,Date,Item ID,Quantity
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,,0
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01BJ0061,10
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01BJ0690,15
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01BJ0746,10
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01CA0754,5
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01CJ0073,10
```

Snippet of File 2:

```
Vendor ID,PO #,Date,Item ID,Quantity
TRLIM,21310023,2/8/2021,0
TRLIM,21310023,4/1/2021,X01BJ0061,10
TRLIM,21310023,1/18/2021,X01BJ0690,15
TRLIM,21310023,4/3/2021,X01BJ0746,10
TRLIM,21310023,8/7/2021,X01CA0754,5
TRLIM,21310023,6/18/2021,X01CJ0073,102
```

Each file has about 30k rows in it.
Each of the two files have the same column names as well. So I would like to compare Vendor, PO, and Item ID and then if they all match Take the dates and compare them.

Here is the code to compare the dates:

```
str_d1 = '2021/10/20'
str_d2 = '2022/2/20'

d1 = datetime.strptime(str_d1, "%Y/%m/%d")
d2 = datetime.strptime(str_d2, "%Y/%m/%d")

delta = (d2 - d1)/7
print(f'Difference is {delta.days} Weeks')
```

So how would I do this?

Comment: I only skimmed, but open both files and read from each one line at a time to create an output file?

Comment: Yes and no, I would like to compare three cerian columns in the files and if Those three match in both take another column in the files and subtract them, that subtracted column becomes the output

Comment: OK, so where are you running into issues?

Comment: i am not sure how to only compare 3 columns and then get the ones to subtract

Comment: If it's a CSV file, you'd first https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp and then, in the resulting array check `if (arr[0] == arr[1] && arr[1] == arr[2]) then..`

Comment: Did you parse the csv file into an object? What object is this? Have you considered / are already using `pandas`? Please show what you tried to _do the thing you want to do_, instead of some tangentially related task.

Comment: My issue is I don't know where to start with the CSV file, Should I convert it into a txt file or a dataframe, Thats why I am asking for the best way to do this

Comment: Well, that depends. How big are your files? Are you doing anything else with this data, other than this subtraction? Also please [edit] your question provide a snippet of both your csv files

Comment: I made some edits and All I would like to do is the subtraction'

Comment: Please provide the snippets as _text_, not as an image. This allows us to copy the CSV to our computers and test any potential solutions. You can [format it using code-fences](/help/formatting) by putting three backticks on the lines before and after the CSV

Comment: My apologies, Edits have been made

Comment: These look like tab-separated or space-separated files, not CSVs?

Comment: @BarryCarter CSV files don't have to be comma-separated.

Comment: Did I do it the rigth way

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Checking the tag definition, it appears you are correct

Comment: @EdwardWynman I rolled back to your previous version because that was better

Comment: Whatever helps I just need help with the comaring the columns and everything

Answer (score 1):

This would be easy to do using pandas, especially since your dataset is quite large

```
import pandas as pd

csv_data1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", delimiter=",")       # Read CSV file
csv_data1["Date"] = csv_data1["Date"].astype("datetime64") # Convert Date column from str to datetime

csv_data2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", delimiter=",")
csv_data2["Date"] = csv_data2["Date"].astype("datetime64")

# Set the index so that the correct rows are subtracted from each other
csv_data1.set_index(["Vendor ID", "PO #", "Item ID"], drop=False, inplace=True)
csv_data2.set_index(["Vendor ID", "PO #", "Item ID"], drop=False, inplace=True)

# Subtract dates. The indexing we did above takes care of subtracting corresponding values
# Then divide # days by 7
difference = (csv_data1["Date"] - csv_data2["Date"]).dt.days / 7
print(difference)
```

If you don't want to use pandas, you could use the `csv` module to read your CSV files, and store the file as a dictionary indexed by vendor and item id.

```
import csv

def read_csv_data(file_name, delim=","):
    csv_data = dict()
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=delim)
        for row in reader:
            index = (row["Vendor ID"], row["PO #"], row["Item ID"])
            csv_data[index] = row

    return csv_data

csv_data1 = read_csv_data("file1.csv")
csv_data2 = read_csv_data("file2.csv")

common_indices = set(csv_data1.keys()).intersection(csv_data2.keys())

for index in common_indices:
    row1 = csv_data1[index]
    row2 = csv_data2[index]
    d1 = datetime.strptime(row1["Date"], "%m/%d/%Y")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(row2["Date"], "%m/%d/%Y")

    delta = d2 - d1
    print(f'Difference is {delta.days / 7} Weeks')
```

Comment: For the `file_name` in the `def` and the `with` statement will I have to put something there? I ask this because I get an error `KeyError: 'Vendor ID'`

Comment: @EdwardWynman no, because `read_csv_data` is a _function_ and we specify the file name when we call the function in `csv_data1 = read_csv_data("file1.csv")`. If you get that error, your example csv files are not representative of your actual csv files. Please provide the correct example

Comment: I added a pic of the files as I am not sure what could be wrong

Comment: It looks like you opened the file in excel and then copied the table here. Open it in a text editor. Your delimiter is likely not a tab @EdwardWynman

Comment: I tried again hopefully its right

Comment: I don't see an edit @EdwardWynman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247312/discussion-between-edward-wynman-and-pranav-hosangadi).